Segfault with memcpy and array
I'm learning C and just ironing out my understanding of how memory is allocated. I'm playing around with the following code and it's segfaulting but I'm not sure why. Any pointers? (no pun intended)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Table {
  int* elements;
} Table;

int main(void) {
  Table* table = {0};
  table->elements = calloc(1, sizeof(int)*3);
  memcpy(table->elements, (int[]) {1, 1, 1}, 3*sizeof(int));

  int* new_elements = calloc(1, sizeof(int)*5);
  memcpy(new_elements, (int[]) {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 5*sizeof(int));

  free(table->elements);
  table->elements = new_elements;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", table->elements[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}


@testing09 You are trying to dereference a null pointer that results in undefined behavior:   Table* table = {0};
table->elements = calloc(1, sizeof(int)*3);

table doesn't need to be a pointer. Table table; would work just as fine (or rather, it would actually work, so work better than the code you currently have... ;-) )

You could easily find that it is the second line in main() that breaks.

@WeatherVane my compiler just shows segfault, is there a way of printing the line number out?

run in gdb.  It prints Segmentation fault. 0x000000000040117c in main () at foo.c:11

...it was easy to return after each line.

Table* table = {0}; initializes table to a null pointer. It points to “nothing.”
Then table->elements = … attempts to use table to refer to the elements member in a structure. But, since table points to nothing, there is no structure and no member to access. Most likely, this results in attempting to access memory that is not mapped for your process and causes a segment fault.
To fix it, you must set table to point to memory for a structure of type Table. Or you could change table to be a structure rather than a pointer and make corresponding changes in the code, such as changing table->elements to table.elements.

Ah thanks- that was a silly error. My main confusion (and where I was looking for an error) was actually this table.elements = new_elements;- why am I allowed to reassign- I thought that if an array decays to a pointer, it is not a valid lvalue?
